# Disabling a Button when document property is not set?

Tags: java, properties, openoffice.org

I am trying to create a plugin for open office and i got stuck at this last final step.

I have a Button that starts my method and I now want that if a specific Property is not given in the opened Document that this button should be dissabled.
The best thing would be if there was a possibility that checks the document right as it gets opened and then decides wether it is enabled or not.

I know how i can dissable this Button but not how I can make it get checked when it starts.

here is some code that the Button does when it gets clicked.. Maybe this helps.

```
public void dispatch(com.sun.star.util.URL aURL,
            com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue[] aArguments) {
        if (aURL.Protocol.compareTo("org.openoffice.demo.optionpagedemo:") == 0) {

            if (aURL.Path.compareTo("DemoOptionCommand") == 0) {

            } else if (aURL.Path.compareTo("CloseCommand") == 0) {



                //Abspeichern des Documents im Temp Ordner
                String storeUrl = "file:///C:/Windows/Temp/Test.odt";
                XModel xDocModel = this.frame.getController().getModel();
                XTextDocument xTextDocument = (XTextDocument) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextDocument.class, xDocModel);
                XStorable xStorable = (XStorable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XStorable.class, xTextDocument);
                //Propertie zum überschreiben setzen 
                PropertyValue[] storeProps = new PropertyValue[1];
                storeProps[0] = new PropertyValue();
                storeProps[0].Name = "Overwrite";
                storeProps[0].Value = new Boolean(true);

                //DocumentId auslesen
                try {
                    getDocumentId();
                } catch (UnknownPropertyException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(OptionPageDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (WrappedTargetException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(OptionPageDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You make button default `style="display:none"`. And after your document properly load or when you want to see this button then use `style="display:block"`